# Asus Strix keyboard only showing P1 P3 M and NKRO lights

Tags: windows

I have the "all-great" Windows 8.1 - 64 bit. I had installed the Asus Strix Keyboard with the latest software version V1.09.04_20150713 and it doesnt work. I also did the FW update and when it says "click into loader" nothing is highlighted for me to click. It is grayed out. Any idea what those lights mean?

These are the only lights working when I plug it into my lenovo idea pad y500 on Windows 8.1 64 bit system - P1 P3 M and NKRO

Comment: Read the keyboard manual?

Comment: Doesnt help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter. I RMAed it and Asus sent out a new keyboard. Turns out it was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

*P1, P3* usually denotes which profile is active. *M* denotes that the macro keys are active, and *NKRO* means N-Key rollover is enabled, which means you can press as many keys at once and it won't drop any characters. You also downloaded a beta version of the drivers, so that may be your problem. **V1.05** is the latest stable build. You should probably install that instead. The driver download is [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Gaming/STRIX_TACTIC_PRO/HelpDesk_Download/)

Comment: Well I installed it and it says no device found. Anyway I can reset this keyboard or its internal memory? Something might have screwed with it. There are no firmware drivers for v1.05. I am stuck. I dont even know which drivers to uninstall, it doesnt show up in the device manager.